# J-Meter :- Performance testing of file upload

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing

I am able to execute the .jmx script created for checking performace testing.
But, I feel, its giving me false results.

I am in impression of this because :-
I have a sampler for upload say "upload" sampler. Before reaching to actual file upload, I am getting redirected to the path "baseURL/node/234" and after that file is getting uploaded.

So, in results , I am seeing, its taking more time than expected as its calculating the time of page load+file upload. And ideally, it should show only "file upload" time.

Can anyone suggest, how can I calculate only file upload time in my sampler

Answer (score 0):

You have to **uncheck** "follow redirect" and "redirect automatically" flags.

Then you have to create to separate samplers, and you should extract the second URL from the response header of the first one.